# PyInstaller failing

Tags: python, pyinstaller, macos-big-sur

MacOS 11.1

I have no idea what this error is trying to tell me.  Are there additional arguments I need to pass to pyinstaller to get it to build me a MacOS executable?

```
$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3

$ python3 -m PyInstaller chambers.py
...

$ dist/chambers/chambers            
[12313] Error loading Python lib '/Users/fy/chambers3/dist/chambers/Python': dlopen: dlopen(/Users/fy/chambers3/dist/chambers/Python, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/fy/chambers3/dist/chambers/Python: code signature invalid for '/Users/fy/chambers3/dist/chambers/Python'

$ file dist/chambers/Python
dist/chambers/Python: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

Comment: macOS has a default python2.7. So you must make sure your pyinstaller install in the right python version.

Comment: @ElapsedSoul.  I installed it using "pip3 install PyInstaller".  So I'm reasonably sure I have the right version.  Is there a way of verifying?

Answer (score 0):

As of Dec 21, 2020, there seems to be an issue with `MacOS 11.1` or `BigSur` update as indicated by another post:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65383402/14386048

Until it gets patched, you can look into two alternatives for completing the same objective of converting a python file into an executable:

1. `py2app` : https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/py2app
2. `cx_freeze` : https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze