# Pyinstaller with PyQt fails to produce functioning .app on Big Sur

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, pyinstaller

I'm trying to use PyQt with PyInstaller to create a simple application on my Mac running Big Sur OS with Python 3.9. The functioning script, "my_script", simply converts miles to kilometers:

```
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QGridLayout, QLineEdit, 
QPushButton

def convert():
    """Takes miles entered, converts them to km, and displays the result"""
    miles = float(entryMiles.text())
    entryKm.setText(str(miles * 1.60934))

app = QApplication([])

rootWindow = QWidget()
rootWindow.setWindowTitle("Miles to kilometers")
rootWindow.resize(500, 200)

gridLayout = QGridLayout(rootWindow)

labelMiles = QLabel('Distance in miles:')
gridLayout.addWidget(labelMiles, 0, 0)

labelKm = QLabel('Distance in kilometers:')
gridLayout.addWidget(labelKm, 2, 0)

entryMiles = QLineEdit()
gridLayout.addWidget(entryMiles, 0, 1)

entryKm = QLineEdit()
gridLayout.addWidget(entryKm, 2, 1)

convertButton = QPushButton('Convert')
gridLayout.addWidget(convertButton, 1, 1)

convertButton.clicked.connect(convert)

rootWindow.show()

app.exec_()
```

At the terminal I moved to the directory containing the script and entered

```
pyinstaller my_script.py --onefile --windowed
```

Everything seemed to work fine and I obtained the dist folder containing my_script.app. However, when I double-clicked on the app, I merely saw an application icon briefly flash in my system tray and then disappear.

Within the application bundle itself I navigated to Contents/MacOS and entered

```
chmod +x my_script
./my_script
```

This resulted in the error message

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

A post at [How to use pyinstaller for MacOs Big Sur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64954725/how-to-use-pyinstaller-for-macos-big-sur) indicates others are facing problems with pyinstaller on Big Sur.

Comment: Have you actually found a way to solve the issue?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I resorted to using tkinter instead of PyQt. 

Sorry I can't be of more help.